# Is there a web-like DB tool for navigating relational databases?

Tags: rdbms

Is there a tool that implements hyperlink-style navigation between tables via foreign keys?  Web-based or native app.

For example, if I have table Users, with a column containing a foreign key reference to table Preferences, such a tool would implement simple 1-click access between the rows of the two tables, automatically creating links based on foreign keys.

I'm using MySQL, but I'm hoping for something that might work on multiple RDBMS systems.

Comment: it would help to know what db you are using (Oracle, MS SQL Server, MYSQL etc.)?

Comment: MySQL, but was hoping for something that perhaps worked on the JDBC level, and could thus work with many different DBs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) will do this for you if properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Show the ['Tadpole DB Hub'](https://github.com/hangum/TadpoleForDBTools/wiki). Tadpole goal is DB Hub for all DB.
Now we are supporting - Amazon RDS, CUBRID, MarisDB, Oracle, MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, MongoDB.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're promoting your own project, [it's required by policy that you say so](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).